# Collision detection on Objects in C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, error-handling, overloading

Ok, so I have got the start of my game almost working I have a object(`pig`) that I control and have objects(`apple`) that moves right to left and the position is random. This all works now I am trying to get the collision working. Problem is that it's not working.

I have commented out the collision coding that is not working if anyone knows why its not working and how to get working please can you let me know how.

error when I uncomment:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection.Add(System.Windows.UIElement)'
>   has some invalid arguments

**My Code (Mainpage)**

namespace game
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        Pig myPig;
        List myapples;

```
    private int appleTimer = 0;
    //int appleCount = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myPig = new Pig();
        myapples = new List<Apple>();

        Image myImg = new Image();
        myImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pig3.png", UriKind.Relative));
        myImg.Width = 80;
        myImg.Height = 60;
        myPig.Content = myImg;
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myPig);
        Canvas.SetLeft(myPig,100);
        Canvas.SetTop(myPig, 50);
        //LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myapples);
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += new EventHandler(CompositionTarget_Rendering);
    }

    public void AddApple(Apple a)
    {
        myapples.Add(a);
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(a);
    }

    public void RemoveApple(Apple a)
    {
        myapples.Remove(a);
        LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(a);
    }

    public void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        appleTimer += 1;
        if (appleTimer > 60)
        {
            appleTimer = 0;
            AddApple(new Apple());
        }

        for (int indx = 0; indx < myapples.Count; indx++)
        {
            myapples[indx].Update(LayoutRoot);
        }

      // if (DetectCollision(myapples, myPig))
       {                  
          // LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(myapples);
        }
    }


    private void UserControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Up)
            this.myPig.Move(Direction.Up);
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            this.myPig.Move(Direction.Down);
        if (e.Key == Key.Left)
            this.myPig.Move(Direction.Left);
        if (e.Key == Key.Right)
            this.myPig.Move(Direction.Right);
    }

    public bool DetectCollision(ContentControl ctrl1, ContentControl ctrl2)
    {

        Rect ctrl1Rect = new Rect(
                new Point(Convert.ToDouble(ctrl1.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)),
                                     Convert.ToDouble(ctrl1.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty))),
                             new Point((Convert.ToDouble(ctrl1.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)) + ctrl1.ActualWidth),
                                     (Convert.ToDouble(ctrl1.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)) + ctrl1.ActualHeight))
                     );

        Rect ctrl2Rect = new Rect(
    new Point(Convert.ToDouble(ctrl2.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)),
                                    Convert.ToDouble(ctrl2.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty))),
                            new Point((Convert.ToDouble(ctrl2.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)) + ctrl2.ActualWidth),
                                    (Convert.ToDouble(ctrl2.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)) + ctrl2.ActualHeight))
                    );

        ctrl1Rect.Intersect(ctrl2Rect);
        return !(ctrl1Rect == Rect.Empty);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: is it this line 'LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myapples);' in ` public MainPage()` that gives the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of elements, not an element. Loop through the list and add each element:

```
foreach (Apple a in myapples) {
  LayoutRoot.Children.Add(a);
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, so place this just after  apples = new List<Apple>(); ?

Comment: @Beep: Instead of `LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myapples);`.